# Cordova write PDF to file

Tags: javascript, cordova, pdf, blob

I whant to write a Cordova App for BlackBerry10 that can write a PDF file (from a SharePointWebservice) and show it.

The PDF is transmitted from a  ASP.NET Webservice as byte[] using

```
byte[] result = spFile.OpenBinary();
```

I'm able to access the file with JSON. This works fine.
To transform the data fromm JSON to usable format I use the following code:

```
var binary = '';
var bytes = new Uint8Array(data.d);
var len = bytes.byteLength;
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    binary += String.fromCharCode(data.d[i]);
}
```

binary is now looking like that:

%PDF-1.5%µµµµ 1 0 obj ... startxref 103423 %%EOF

Here is the Code to write it to a file using cordova-plugin-file.

```
var blob = new Blob([binary], { type: 'application/pdf' });
fileWriter.write(blob);
```

It works fine for txt files, but when I try to write the PDF file I get an empty document.
I have also tryed window.btoa(binary) instead of just using binary.

Any ideas what ho to create the data blob, or which format to use?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have solved the Problem by using the cordova fileOpener2 Plugin. I am using the var "bytes" from above filled into the new named variable data.

```
    try {
        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.externalApplicationStorageDirectory, function (directoryEntry) {
            directoryEntry.getFile(fileName, { create: true }, function (fileEntry) {

                fileEntry.createWriter(function (fileWriter) {
                    fileWriter.onwriteend = function (e) {

                        cordova.plugins.fileOpener2.open(cordova.file.externalApplicationStorageDirectory + fileName, 'application/pdf',
                            {
                                error: function (e) {
                                    ...
                                },
                                success: function () {
                                    ... //PDF has opened
                                }
                            }
                        );
                    };

                    fileWriter.onerror = function (e) {
                        ...
                    };

                    //Blob erstellen - Blackberry File Plugin verwenden
                    var blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/pdf' });

                    fileWriter.write(blob);

                }, function onerror(e) {
                    ...
                });
            }, function onerror(e) {
                ...
            });
        }, function onerror(e) {
            ...
        });

    } catch (e) {
        ...
    }
```

Used Plugins:
cordova-plugin-file & 
cordova-plugin-file-opener2

For other file types like PNG I use (for jpg just replace png with jpg):

```
var blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'image/png' });
```

to write the file and

```
window.open(cordova.file.externalApplicationStorageDirectory + fileName);
```

to open and show it.

Showing txt files is quite easy, you can do it like that:

```
if (fileName.split('.')[1].indexOf("txt") > -1) {
    var blob = new Blob([bytes], { type: 'text/plain' });
    var objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    window.open(objectUrl);
}
```

This worked for me, comment if you have any questions.

Comment: What is the data here? I think that is the question.